# How to do a path based reverse proxy with Heroku?

Tags: reverse-proxy, subdomain, heroku

We have a Rails application running on Heroku on `www.example.com`.

Now for some paths we want to route the traffic to a completely separate Wordpress instance (e.g. for `www.example.com/blog` and `www.example.com/about`).
We do not want to use subdomains.

Now we *could* set up a dedicated HAProxy, e.g. on AWS, that does reverse proxying based on the request path but we wonder if there was a simpler alternative using only Heroku infrastructure?

Comment: Your best bet is probably putting a multi-origin CloudFront distribution in front of the Heroku app.